# Variable undefined when waking from sleep in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, macos, google-chrome

Using Mac OS X 10.8.4, Chrome 27 (latest stable).

I have a script that every X seconds (with `setInterval()`) makes an AJAX call with jQuery to see if there's still a connection to the server (heartbeat). It posts some data and depending on if it succeeded or not, calls other functions.

It works fine *until* my Mac goes to sleep (screen black, HDD powers down, etc.), I wake it up and the AJAX call failed and tried to call a function (variable) that apparently no longer exists:

```
POST http://mywebsite.com/index.php  jquery.min.js:4
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'onLost' of undefined
```

`onLost` is a function within other variables, such as `mylib` and `anotherlib`. They are instantiated very early in loading the page. The code is a lot more complex, but here's a simplified version:

```
var mylib = new mylib();

mylib.anotherlib = function() { this.onLost = function() { ... }}

setInterval() { function() { $.ajax({ failed: mylib.anotherlib.onLost }); }, 10000);
```

After the error occurs, my script behaves as normal. It can access `mylib` and `onLost()` just fine. I know browsers implement `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` when the computer sleeps differently (doesn't Chrome pause it or slow it down or something?), but it's still an odd error.

Could it be the way I'm calling `failed` or how jQuery's `$.ajax()` does its thing?

Comment: We need more context to see how `mylib` is defined.

Comment: @Barmar Added (mostly).